# What causes blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, wysiwyg, blur

I'm trying to make my own Wysiwyg redactor.

I have a problem: when I click the control button contenteditable div loses focus and make some actions, which I'd like to make only if was not clicked control-button.

So is there something like this in javascript:

```
$('#tarea').blur(function(event){
    if($(event.reasonelement).is('#bold')) return false;
    //Other actions here...
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: How about when you click a button, set a variable to true, and when the blur function runs, check if the variable is true, and if it is, don't run the rest of the code (but set the variable to false to it'll run the second time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be capturing the document's click event and decide what to do with that:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  elem = $("#tarea");
  if (!elem.is(event.target) && elem.has(event.target).length == 0) {
    // do your stuff here..
  }
});
```

*PS: This should work for all kind of elements and not just textareas.*

Comment: $('document')  document is not a tag:: $(document) is what you want